# Laravel event doesn't send the right data to Pusher

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, broadcast, pusher

I have a `logController` which has `show()` method. In my `show()` method, I am returning a single data that retrieved from the database.

```js
$report = Log::select('logs.id')
  ->where('logs.id', '=', '1')
  ->get();
// event(new NewLog($report));
return $report;
```

In this case, the returning value is `1`. I am also expecting that data will be sent to Pusher will be the same as the result of the query. But the data that are being sent to Pusher are `id, user_id`, date` etc. I just want to send the single data that I fetched which is logs.id.

Here is my NewLog Event:

```js
class NewLog implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    public $log;

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($log)
    {
        $this->log = $log;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('logs');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use the find() static function on Log.
return $report will give you object.if you want to access the property of that object use as $report->property_name;

try using the below code:

```
$report = Log::find(1);
$event = event(new NewLog($report->id));
return $report->id;
```

OR

```
$report = Log::select('logs.id')
  ->where('logs.id', '=', '1')
  ->get();
// event(new NewLog($report->id));
return $report;
```

Comment: What if I have a query like this? [link](https://imgur.com/a/JdvbP) ? It sends the log.* and not including the users.first_name and users.last_name

Comment: Solved. I added `->toArray()`